# Pandas groupby and apply with unique is very slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas, group-by

I'm new to pandas so I apologies in advance if the answer is obvious but I can't find any answers on the topic. 
I have a set of a data of about two million rows and I'm trying to group by one column and create unique lists as aggregated values of other two columns:

```
    keys = # list of keys from an s3 paginator
    dfs = []
    for key in keys:
        print(key)
        match = re.search('^[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}/(.*)/(.*)_batch_request.csv$', key, re.IGNORECASE)
        df = pd.read_csv('s3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key), names = ['id'])
        df['environment']=match.group(1)
        df['request_id']=match.group(2)
        dfs.append(df)
    all = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()
    all.groupby('id').agg({'environment': 'unique', 'request_id': 'unique'})
```

The last line reduces the original set to about 300k rows and it takes a couple of minutes. The time needed to group does not seem directly related to the initial size of the frame as attempts with smaller input produce very similar results.

Maybe I am mistaken but I was expecting much faster performance on an i7 with 4Gb of RAM. If I use `nunique` instead of `unique` just to count the unique elements, it runs in ~15 seconds.

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected performance?

Thanks

Comment: please provide a [MCVE], with a small example of your data and your expected output

Comment: maybe have a look at [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Before doing the `groupby`, it might be faster to do `drop_duplicates(subset=['id','environment','request_id'])` than just using `unique` in `agg` on the full data. But it's just a guess, like this I'm not sure about performance difference.

Comment: @sacul please find example [here (~5Mb)](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow-samples/51717620.tar.gz)